# Pandas groupby count: count only if number

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, count, pandas-groupby

I have a DF with several fields. For example:

```
      Year_end  Week_end Integrado Probs  Duration_hours        Router_name
1225      2017         2        si     1             0.7   C3617_AI670_SARA
1562      2017         2        si   N/A            23.0   CF641_PTC70_SARA
1722      2017         2        si     1           314.1   CH126_R1970_SARA
1731      2017         2        si     1           265.9   CH205_BRR70_SARA
1760      2017         2        si   512             1.5   CO068_ARI70_SARA
1936      2017         2        si    32            23.4   CO721_LE370_SARA
2011      2017         2        si   N/A             0.5   CR015_EMP70_SARA
2335      2017         2        si     1           340.3   RJ046_LR170_SARM
2337      2017         2        si   N/A             2.5   RJ077_LR370_SARM
2342      2017         2        si   N/A             2.0   RJ092_RJA70_SARA
2346      2017         2        si     1           338.3   RJ204_LR670_SARM
2350      2017         2        si   N/A             2.7   RJ210_RJC70_SARA
```

I'm doing groupby such as:

```
fieldsX = ['Year_end','Week_end']
f = { 'Router_name':['count'], 'Probs':['count'], 'Duration_hours':['mean'] }
a = a.groupby(fieldsX).agg(f)
```

This is working fine. The only problem is with field `Probs` that has both numbers and a specific string `N/A`. I only want to count all the numbers **BUT NOT** the `N/A` occurrences.

So, `count(Router_name) = 12` but `count(Probs) **should** be 7`. Instead my `count(Probs) = 12`.

How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Try replacing 'N/A' with np.nan. Or maybe they re already.

Comment: Change `f` to something like `f = { 'Router_name':['count'], 'Probs':[lambda x: x.replace('N/A', np.nan).count()], 'Duration_hours':['mean'] }`.

Comment: I'd do something like: `df.Probs = pd.to_numeric(df.Probs, errors='coerce')` to 'clean' the data from N/A values in Probs column.

Comment: Thank you, guys. Both the answers did solve my issue! Thanks!

Comment: While mine worked, I would highly recommend going with what @AntonvBR provided. It's cleaner and it makes obvious that `Probs` is a numeric column.

Comment: @Abdou Yep, but there could be a rare case where yours could be useful. Nice trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of your problem:

```
import pandas as pd

data = dict(letters = list('abc'), numbers=[1,2,'N/A'])

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Before
print(df.groupby('letters').count())

# Fix it by converting column to numeric
df.numbers = pd.to_numeric(df.numbers, errors='coerce')

# After
print(df.groupby('letters').count())
```

Will print:

```
         numbers
letters         
a              1
b              1
c              1
         numbers
letters         
a              1
b              1
c              0
```

---

However, seeing as you have 'N/A' in the first place... Have a look at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv and specifically the param: na_values. If this was the way you read the data is should be cleaned initially already. If this is how you got the dataframe.